# Отображение сетки в Unity 2020

Tags: unity3d

Не отображается  сетка в 2D режиме на сцене. Скриншот прилагаю - кнопка переключения отображения сетки нажата. Как включить сетку?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дело не в цвете: в Preferencies поменял цвет сетки - все равно не видно

Answer (score 1):

Была такая же проблема, помог сброс настроек шаблонов окна: Window - Layouts - Reset All Layouts